# SharePoint authentication after demoting a domain controller

Tags: active-directory, configuration, domain

I have an issue in regards to a domain controller being demoted.  SharePoint is not installed on this DC.

When the dc is demoted in sites and services for AD SP has kittens and can't auth at all.  Just keeps prompting.
When we bring back up the DC and re-add to sites and services it then works as expected.

I worked with our network team and did some trace logging and found that it is only authing to that one DC and does not hit the others in the sites and services.

Is this cached someplace?

I'm not aware of anywhere in the configuration where this would be kept.

Server Info:
SharePoint Server 2010 enterprise
Windows Server 2008 R2

Thank you and let me know what other info I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

The "caching" is most likely happening within Windows itself.  After demoting the domain controller, reboot your SharePoint servers.  After the reboot, Windows will attempt to contact the appropriate domain controller.

Comment: It's been a while since we tried to turn off the dc.  I'll give this a shot this weekend and let you know the result.  Thanks for the response.